# How to make a for loop that restarts the circle animation before it is finished, making it look like a pulsating circle

Tags: javascript, for-loop, canvas, jquery-animate, geometry

I have the code of a growing circle but i am trying to make several circles grow in canvas/javascript. I want to make it look like its pulsing, constantly pumping out circles, like sound waves. I'm quite new to coding so i'm not sure of the syntax but something along the lines of `if(radius of circle> width of canvas/30px){create new circle}`
here is the code i have so far

```
window.onload=function(){
    function animate() {
        var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx= c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

        if(i > 200) {
            i = 1;
        }

        if( i > 40) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(c.width/2, c.width/2, i-40, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
            ctx.lineWidth = 7;
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        i++;
        setTimeout(animate, 10);
    }
    var i = 0;
    animate();
  }
}
```

i tried putting in `if(i>30px)animate();` and other variations, but no luck. thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code for the animation.

```html
<html>
<body>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    function animate() {
        var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx= c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

        if(i > 300) { // adjust the place need to stop the animation at canvas, how many pixels that the stop point close to the origin
            i = 1; 
        }

        if( i > 1) {
     var j = 0;
     while(j<50){ // number of circles in the wave (50/5)
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(c.width/2, c.height+300, i+(j*5), 0, 2 * Math.PI, true); // i=(j*5) adjust the distance between circles
      ctx.lineWidth = 7;
      ctx.stroke();
             j += 5;
     }
        }
        i++;
        setTimeout(animate, 10);
    }
    var i = 0;
    animate();
}
</script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer!!! and for the code! i've made 2 canvases and will use this code to make one low frequency and one high frequency animation. Is there any reason to why i can't just copy the code, alter the width a little and assign it to canvas2? the animation isn't playing :/

Comment: You are using two different contexts for the canvases?

Comment: they both have 2d in getContext if that's what you mean!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ush83pfb/ for some reason, neither play in fiddle, both codes work in my html document, however they will only play 1 at a time. If both codes are there, only myCanvas2 will display, if myCanvas2 is deleted, myCanvas1 will play.. thank you for answering!

Comment: Insert both animate1 and animate2 inside the same window.onload function. And, avoid multi declaration for i variable.